# Issue Creating Events Using MBCalendarKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbcalendarkit

I am using MBCalendarKit in my app and I can create events like this:

```
CKCalendarEvent* aCKCalendarEvent = [[CKCalendarEvent alloc] init];
    [_infoDict setObject:@"Joint Meetings with KY State Horticulture Society, KY Vegetable Growers Association, KY Vineyard Society, and KY Farmer Market Association \nEmbassy Suites\nLexington, KY" forKey:@"Jan Joint"];
    aCKCalendarEvent.date = [dateformatter dateFromString: @"01/06/2014"];
    aCKCalendarEvent.title = @"Joint Meetings";
    aCKCalendarEvent.info = [_infoDict objectForKey:@"Jan Joint"];
    [eventsArray addObject: aCKCalendarEvent];
    [_eventsDict setObject: eventsArray forKey: [NSDate dateWithDay:06 month:01 year:2014]];
```

I can create another event on the same day like this:

```
[_infoDict setObject:@"Washington, D.C." forKey:@"Congress Convenes"];
    aCKCalendarEvent = [[CKCalendarEvent alloc] init];
    aCKCalendarEvent.date = [dateformatter dateFromString: @"01/06/2014"];
    aCKCalendarEvent.title = @"113th Congress Convenes";
    [eventsArray addObject: aCKCalendarEvent];
    [_eventsDict setObject: eventsArray forKey: [NSDate dateWithDay:06 month:01 year:2014]];
```

and then I can create another event on a different day like this:

```
eventsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [_infoDict setObject:@"Hilton Hotel \nMemphis, TN" forKey:@"Forage & Grassland"];
    aCKCalendarEvent = [[CKCalendarEvent alloc] init];
    aCKCalendarEvent.date = [dateformatter dateFromString: @"01/12/2014"];
    aCKCalendarEvent.title = @"American Forage & Grassland Council Annual Conference";
    [eventsArray addObject: aCKCalendarEvent];
    [_eventsDict setObject: eventsArray forKey: [NSDate dateWithDay:12 month:01 year:2014]];
```

I'm trying to loop through a plist file which contains all the events to create all of them.  I can do that like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Events" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dictPri = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSMutableArray *arrEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[dictPri objectForKey:@"List"]];

    // Loop through each item in List array of Events.plist

    for (NSDictionary *dict in arrEvents)
    {
        NSString *titleString = nil;
        NSString *date = nil;
        titleString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"Title"]];
        date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"Date"]];
        // NSDate *dateVariable = [dateformatter dateFromString:date];

        // Create events

        eventsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        aCKCalendarEvent = [[CKCalendarEvent alloc] init];
        aCKCalendarEvent.title = titleString;
        aCKCalendarEvent.date = [dateformatter dateFromString: date];
        [eventsArray addObject: aCKCalendarEvent];
        [_eventsDict setObject:eventsArray forKey:aCKCalendarEvent.date];
    }
```

The problem is that if I have multiple events on the same day, only the newest one shows up.  I can take out the line `eventsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` but then the new events not only show up on the correct day with other events, but they show up on other days as well.  So I thought I could throw in something like this to check if I need that line and then add the event to the eventsDict but I get `-[CKCalendarEvent isEqualToDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc6bb880` on `if ([[eventsArray objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToDate:aCKCalendarEvent.date])`:

```
BOOL dateExists;

        for (int i = 0; i < [eventsArray count]; i++)
        {
            if ([[eventsArray objectAtIndex:i]isEqualToDate:aCKCalendarEvent.date])
            {
                // Array already contains object with this date

                dateExists = YES;
            }
            else
            {
                dateExists = NO;
            }

            NSLog(@"%c", dateExists);
        }

        if (dateExists == YES)
        {
            [eventsArray addObject:aCKCalendarEvent];
            [_eventsDict setObject:eventsArray forKey:aCKCalendarEvent.date];
        }
        else
        {
            eventsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [eventsArray addObject:aCKCalendarEvent];
            [_eventsDict setObject:eventsArray forKey:aCKCalendarEvent.date];
        }
```

So basically, I need a way to loop through the plist and determine when if the program needs to init the eventsArray on each new event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing event with date. See below code which is comparing event date.

```
if ([[(CKCalendarEvent *)[eventsArray objectAtIndex:i] date]isEqualToDate:aCKCalendarEvent.date])
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the unrecognized selector problem.